# Java Drools how to properly load .rf file? (reverse execution, why?)

Tags: spring-boot, drools

Hello i was migrating from drools from 5.1.0 to 7.66.0.FINAL, it is working properly on .drl files but .rf files are probably not loaded correctly.

here is my old core 5.1.0 to load .drl and .rf

```
    private KnowledgeBase computationKnowledgeBase;

    public void loadDrls() {
        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
        kbuilder.add(newReaderResource("Calc.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
        kbuilder.add(newReaderResource("Calc.rf"), ResourceType.DRF);
        if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
            this.log.error(kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
        }

        this.computationKnowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration());
        this.computationKnowledgeBase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());


        StatefulKnowledgeSession session = this.computationKnowledgeBase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            session.addEventListener(new LoggingAgendaEventListener(log));
        }
        session.insert(something);
        session.insert(something2);
        session.fireAllRules();
        session.dispose();
        }
    }
```

here is my 7.66.0 code:
here is my old core 5.1.0 to load .drl and .rf

```
        
    private KieBase computationKnowledgeBase;

    public void loadDrls() {
        KieBase knowledgeBase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration());
        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(knowledgeBase);
        kbuilder.add(newReaderResource("Calc.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
        kbuilder.add(newReaderResource("Calc.rf"), ResourceType.DRF);
        if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
            log.error(kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
        }

        this.computationKnowledgeBase = knowledgeBase;
        
        StatefulKnowledgeSession session = (StatefulKnowledgeSession) this.rulesCache.getCalculationKnowledgeBase().newKieSession();


        session.insert(something);
        session.insert(something2);
        session.fireAllRules();
        session.dispose();
    }
```

dependency:

```
        <!-- Drools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>${drools.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

problem is that it does load .rf file but it does not working properly (on .rl file we've got order of rules and it does not execute in correct order how it worked on older drools)

**EDIT**:
I have updated code with sessions, problem is that in new drools there are not StateFullKnowledgeSession only newKieSession.
Problem with this is that on .rf file i have order of execution rule methods, but when i upgrades it like this, drools are working but order of execution (defined on .rf file) is not working properly.

**EDIT2**:
it is related to this answer, on drools v5 it is executing .rf correctly
on v 7.66.FINAL it is executing on reverse order

https://github.com/tenkyu/drools-flow-order
https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage/c/GK5OPUXQl5Q/m/NZQFVsYvBQAJ

Has anybody had this problem?

**SOLUTION**:
**downgrade drools to 6.4.0 version**, it is version where .rf files are not executing in reverse order

Comment: You're going to need to expand a bit on "not working properly". Give an example, and a test that passes in one version and fails in the next. Your problem isn't that you're not loading it, your problem is that you _are_ loading it but it's not working as you expect it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas i have defined order of rule execution on .rf file, on older version it is working good and order is fired by .rf file, but after upgrade it is not doing rule order firing properly.

Comment: We need to see the .rf file definition. The GitHub repo you linked to doesn't have an .rf file. Basically a reproducible example, which usually is just a rule, but in this case is how you've defined the rule flow transitions.